# directx9 button and directx9 gui

Tags: button, user-interface, directx, directx-9

I´m searching for a predefined class or stuct in directx, which has the functionality of a button.

I want to program a litte game and I have learned, that it is very usefull to use already existing classes and functions. But, the doc of directx is so big, that I can´t find the things, which I´m needing.

Now I´m searching for a button class or a GUI.

If I write it on my own, then it will take a lot of time, and I want to create a game and not a GUI. So I´m searching for a already existing GUI, which I have only to inlucde.

I´m using c++
directx9
visual studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

The Native DirectX SDK does not provide the GUI functionality, but you can take a look at DXUT(that's ok if you are using DirectX9, DXUT was deprecated since DirectX 11), it is a framework developed by Microsoft which intend to simplify the process to build up a DirectX project, it contains the GUI controls, like button.

you can also use the classic win32 API to build up your control if you don't mind the outlook:).

Comment: Is there any aquivalent to DXUT in directx11?

Comment: you can take a look at [DirectX Toolkit](http://directxtk.codeplex.com/), but I don't think they have the GUI like DXUT now.

Comment: @user2288390 DXUT is available for Direct3D 11 [here](https://dxut.codeplex.com/).